# Finding the derivative via implicit differentiation of an exponent?

Tags: calculus

Am I doing this one correct. Wolfram Alpha says otherwise but I'm not sure where I go wrong:

$$y = x^{\sin (x)}$$

Wolfram alpha says the derivative is:

$$y'(x) = x^{(\sin(x) - 1)} \cdot (\sin(x) + x \cdot \log(x) \cdot \cos(x))$$

But here are my calcs:

$$\ln y = \sin(x) \cdot \ln(x)$$

$$\frac{1}{y} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\sin(x)}{x} + \ln(x)\cos(x)$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x^{\sin(x)} \cdot \left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x} + \ln(x)\cos(x)\right)$$

Comment: the way you did it is fine; in fact, i quite like it (i usually use exponents instead of logs to get the same outcome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the same answer since

$$x^{\sin(x)}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}+\cos(x)\log(x)\right)=x^{\sin(x)-1}\left(\sin(x)+x\log(x)\cos(x)\right)$$  multiply the bracket by $x$ and $x^{\sin(x)}$ by $\frac1x$

Comment: sorry, can you clarify? Can you take me from the left to the right?

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how x^{sin(x)} goes to x^{sin(x) -1}

Comment: $x^a \times \frac1x = x^{a-1}$. Meanwhile $\frac{b}{x} \times x= b$ and $c\times x= xc$.  So $x^{a}\left(\frac b x +c\right)= x^{a-1}(b+xc)$

Comment: ohhhh because $\frac{1}{x}$ is $x^{-1}$...

Answer (score 3):

Note that the two expression are equal, indeed

$$x^{(\sin x - 1)}=x^{\sin x}\cdot x^{-1}$$

and thus

$$y'(x) = x^{(\sin x - 1)} \cdot (\sin x + x \cdot \log x  \cdot \cos x )= x^{\sin x } \cdot\frac1x (\sin x + x \cdot \log x \cdot \cos x)$$

Comment: sorry, can you clarify? Can you take me from the left to the right?

Comment: @Jwan622 simply note that the result is the same, indeed for algebraic exponential rules $x^{(\sin x - 1)}=x^{\sin x}\cdot x^{-1}$

Comment: @Jwan622 sorry I thought it was clear!

Answer (score 2):

$$y=x^{\sin(x)}$$
Take the logarithm of both sides:
$$\log(y)=\sin(x)\log(x)$$
Now differentiate both sides with respect to $x$:
$$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}+\cos(x)\log(x)$$
$$y'=y*\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}+\cos(x)\log(x)\right)$$
$$y'=x^{\sin(x)}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}+\cos(x)\log(x)\right)$$
WolframAlpha's answer:
$$y'=x^{\sin(x)-1}\left(\sin(x)+x\log(x)\cos(x)\right)$$
$$y'=\frac{x^{\sin(x)}}{x^1}\left(\sin(x)+x\log(x)\cos(x)\right)$$
$$y'=x^{\sin(x)}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}+\frac{\log(x)\cos(x)x}{x}\right)$$
So both of the answers are the same.

Comment: is the derivative of log(x) really 1/x?

Comment: @Jwan622 Yes, the derivate of $\log_e(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$. $\log_e(x)=\log(x)=\ln(x)$. But sometimes $\log(x)$ means $\log_{10}(x)$, but it's base $e$ here.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Use the general formula

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x)^{g(x)} = f(x)^{g(x)}\left(g'(x)\ln(f(x)) + g(x)\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)$$

Comment: Are you deriving this formula every time you use it, or you can keep it in your mind?

Comment: I have it in my mind, it's simple because $f^g = e^{g \ln(f)}$ hence it's about deriving an exponential. It's easy to derive and remember!

Comment: It might be because of my bad memory, but I find it easier to derive than remember.

Comment: @Botond Both methods are fine! If you don't remember, derive it! :D (pun intended)

Comment: @Botond Remembering this is easy. First, take the derivative assuming $g$ is constant, then take the derivative assuming $f$ is constant. Now add the two! (I have no idea why this works, but it does.)